# IBM Cognos DB2 configuration

Tags: db2, cognos

I'm trying to configure IBM Cognos 10.2.1 with IBM DB2 - 10.5.1 on AIX 7.1. The default installation (in cogstartup.xml) of Cognos comes with Derby database. Cognos with default configuration starts successfully. Dispatcher page comes up but with an error that indicates that Content Store (i.e. Derby) is not available.

However, if I replace the database with DB2, Cognos does not start properly i.e. dispatcher URL is inaccessible.

Can you please see what can be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing config for server end or framework manager client end? what i can tell you is once you passed config in FM and want to change it, you gotta remove two Pkey and comm folders before you trying to save your config

Answer (score 0):

You might need to copy `db2` `jar` files to `cognos` lib folder when you change the database from Derby to DB2, directly edit the `cogstartup.xml` with DB2 data configurations.